# Redis: Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6388: bind: Permission denied

Tags: redis, centos7

I have fresh ContOS 7 and redis (Redis 3.2.12) on it. Redis work great on default port 6379, but when I change the port in redis.conf I have Error msg in logs: # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6388: bind: Permission denied. My firewall is disable (sudo firewall-cmd --state not running) and I don't know who can block it.

Comment: Are SELinux enable? Can you try to set permissive to see what happens?

Comment: Are SELinux is enable by default? what to do with it?

Comment: Yes on Centos it comes enabled by default. Let's just make a test, disable it following this link https://www.certdepot.net/selinux-set-enforcing-and-permissive-modes/ and try again the port 6388;

Comment: Thank you a lot! SELinux is the problem!

Comment: Ok but is not a good practice disabling SELinux, enable SELinux again and configure SELinux  to accept your port for REDIS using the follow:
# semanage port -a -t redis_port_t -p tcp 6388

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, As Gabriel Pereira mentioned, configuring SELinux to accept port for redis fixed my problem.

`semanage port -a -t redis_port_t -p tcp 6388`

remember to change `6388` to your specified port number.

Answer (score 2):

By default the SELinux is enable in your CentOS. Check it `sudo vi /etc/selinux/config` and you need to change SELINUX enforcing to disabled.